# Parallel ForEach using Current Synchronization Context

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm a bit new to threading in C#, but I've inherited a codebase that is doing quite a bit of it. I'm looking at some multithreaded code segments that seem to be logically running sequentially. Here's an example:

```
// Draw the nodes.
var factory = new TaskFactory(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
var drawingTasks = new List<Task>(nodePoints.Count);
Parallel.ForEach(nodePoints, nodePoint =>
{
    Task task = factory.StartNew(() => DrawNode(token, nodePoint, groupList), token, TaskCreationOptions.None, factory.Scheduler);
    if (task != null)
        drawingTasks.Add(task);
});

await factory.ContinueWhenAll(drawingTasks.ToArray(), result =>
{
    _event.Publish(new MapNodesDrawnEvent());
});
```

Debugging the application reveals this is executing on the main thread, which I assume is also the UI thread. Since the new threads are using the current synchronization context isn't this just executing all of these task sequentially on the main thread? If so is there any value to doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `List<Task>` is not thread safe, you can not use it inside a `Parallel.ForEach` without locking (even though you pre-sized the list it still is not safe).
2. If all you are doing is starting up a new thread with a TaskFactory there is no reason to do that in parallel. Calling StartNew is incredibly fast so there is no need.
3. The `Parallel` classes uses the calling thread as one of the worker threads so it is possible that the calling thread could be used inside a Parallel.ForEach
4. You called `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` which if called from a thread that had its SynchronizationContext set, this is likely the UI thread or a background thread with `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(` called, will cause tasks that are started with that scheduler to be run from the UI thread.

The only thing the posted code gives you (if you fixed issue 1 so it was nolonger buggy) would be you would be queuing the work on to the end of the message queue to be processed. This could be useful if you want to defer work to later but using [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke(v=vs.110).aspx) is a much better way to do it.